# Unknown column 'data' in 'where clause' while using 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So i have 3 tables that have same column named *kode_dosen*

1. **matkul**
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30F0P.png)
2. **dosen**
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/133Oo.png)
3. **hasilstudi**
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM7Mg.png)

And i have 2 tables that have same column named *email*

1. **user**
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjDse.png)
2. **dosen**

And i want to make study result form that the input will be inserted to **hasilstudi**

The condition is:

1. I fetch *kode_dosen* to **hasilstudi** from *kode_dosen* from **matkul** and from *kode_dosen* **dosen** from user(dosen) that currently logged in (COMPLETED)

This is the model from condition 1 that completed

```
public function sedo() {        
            return $this->db->get_where('dosen', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
        }
```

$this->session->userdata('email') is from auth model for login

2. I fetch *kode_matkul* to **hasilstudi** from *kode_matkul* from **matkul** by select option, but based on user(dosen) who logged in with *kode_dosen* registered in **matkul** (NOT_COMPLETED)

This is the model from condition 2 that not_completed

```
public function studidos() {
            $studos = $this->M_Dosen->sedo();
            $kode = $studos['kode_dosen'];
            $query = "SELECT matkul.kode_dosen, matkul, matkul.kode_matkul
                            FROM matkul JOIN dosen
                            ON matkul.kode_dosen = dosen.kode_dosen
                            WHERE dosen.kode_dosen = $kode";
            $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
        }
```

And the view is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Kode Dosen</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_dosen" name="kode_dosen" value="<?= $sedo['kode_dosen']; ?>" placeholder="" readonly>
    <?= form_error('kode_dosen', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Kode Matkul</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="kode_matkul">
    <?php foreach($studidos as $stud) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $stud['kode_matkul']; ?>"><?= $stud['matkul']; ?> (<?= $stud['kode_matkul']; ?>)</option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

The problem is, that the condition 2 is error with error code

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'HG01' in 'where clause'

SELECT matkul.kode_dosen, matkul, matkul.kode_matkul FROM matkul JOIN dosen ON matkul.kode_dosen = dosen.kode_dosen WHERE dosen.kode_dosen = HG01

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/praktek-codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 692

I've few changes in studidos(), but the error still occurs, either database error or the select option shows nothing

What should i do to complete condition 2?
If there is already the answer from similar thread, please refer it here

Thanks for the answer

Comment: You need to put `$kcode` in quotes, or better is to use prepared statements.

Comment: I works! So what i do is:
1. Put $kcode in quotes

$query = "SELECT *
       FROM matkul JOIN dosen
       ON matkul.kode_dosen = dosen.kode_dosen
       WHERE dosen.kode_dosen = '$kode'";

2. Add return to return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

Thanks for your answer, Sir

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So i just made a few changes in my model:

1. Put $kode in quotes

```
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM matkul JOIN dosen
            ON matkul.kode_dosen = dosen.kode_dosen
            WHERE dosen.kode_dosen = '$kode'";
```

2. Add return to `$this->db->query($query)->result_array();`

And it works!